# What is a real or a complex eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, definition

In my course of ODE, they talk about real or complex eigenvectors. What is it exactly ? Is a an eigenvector s.t. the eigenvalue is real or complex ? Or is it an eigenvector s.t. the component of the vector is real or complex ?

Comment: A real eigenvector has only real components. Otherwise it is a complex eigenvector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An eigen vector is real /complex if the coordinates are real/complex.